# How do I get object build info out of a Go library?

Tags: go

I'm trying to build a Go program where I have a required library on my system in binary form. However, `go build` fails with

```
object is [linux amd64 go1.1.1 X:none] expected [linux amd64 go1.1.2 X:none]
```

I see what the immediate problem is: the static library was built with an older version of Go. How can I read that information from the `.a` file directly? (I can see it with `strings library.a | grep '^go object'`, but is there something that's *meant* to output the build string? (And, what is that string properly called?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.a` files the Go compiler produces are managed using the `pack` tool.  The metadata used to link the package is found in the `__.PKGDEF` member of the archive.

You can extract this file from an archive to `stdout` with:

```
go tool pack p path/to/package.a __.PKGDEF
```

It starts with the build signature you're after, so you could either take the first line or grep for `^go object` as you were with the output of `strings` (this should be a bit more reliable, in case that text shows up as a constant in the program code).